# Pandas Panel resampling alternatives

Tags: python, pandas, panel, netcdf, resampling

I often use pd.Series.resample(), and am wondering if there is a way to resample/ interpolate monthly gridded data in the form (time,lat, lon) to say 'MS' (monthly start). I understand the feature is not directly implemented in Panel. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the [xray](http://xray.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) package.  It is an N-dimensional labeled array package that extends much of the pandas resampling/group-by functionality.  It is a pure python package so is easy to install and includes some really nice utilities for netCDF I/O.

For example, you could resample a xray DataArray object `da` to a month start frequency like this:

```
da_ms = da.resample('MS', dim='time', how='mean')
```

Full disclosure, I am one of the xray developers, but this is exactly why xray has been developed.

Comment: Thanks @sea_hydro! I'll give it a try. Thanks for developing to cater to such needs.

Comment: I'll add an xray endorsement, from someone (myself) not involved in the project at all.  xray is fantastic.

Comment: xray is axactly what I was looking for! Here I wrote a quick review on it:http://hrishichandanpurkar.blogspot.com/2015/10/xray-package-brilliant-little-tool-for.html