# Alternative for Pandas resample

Tags: pandas, for-loop, time-series, resampling

I am looking for a solution to `resample` `time series` data on a big scale (tens or hundreds of millions of data records). `Pandas` `resample()` worked well until about 10 mio data records were reached, afterwards it actually stopped working, because the hardware had not enough memory. I had this problem several times with Pandas on huge datasets. But if I just used a for loop on huge datasets, I could read the data and work with it, even if it was much slower. Does anybody know a good solution to `resample time series data` without `pandas`?

The source of the data is a MySQL server and the records contain OHLC data and a timestamp. The frequency of the time series is 1 minute and the resampling frequencies are 5 min, 30 min, 1h, 6h, 1d, 1w, 1m, which I all store into different tables. I consider to switch in future to mongoDB.

Comment: Since resampling only requires local (as opposed to global) data, you should be
able to solve the problem by break your time series into chunks. Load one chunk
into a Pandas Series at a time.  Resample the Series and store the
result. Repeat the process for each chunk.  To get more specific than this we
need more information. It would help to know the source of the time series -- is
it in a CSV (what format?) or a database? (what server? what schema?). What is
the frequency of the time series and what is the resampling frequency? Where and in what format do you want the data stored?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my question with the corresponding info

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:
[Pandas Panel resampling alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130490/pandas-panel-resampling-alternatives)

Meanwhile the package is called xarray. Although you can check out dask, which together with xarray can offer fast, parallel resampling (and many other numpy and pandas functions).